# Pandas rank based on several columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe :

```
event_id  occurred_at  user_id
   19148   2015-10-01        1
   19693   2015-10-05        2
   20589   2015-10-12        1
   20996   2015-10-15        1
   20998   2015-10-15        1
   23301   2015-10-23        2
   23630   2015-10-26        1
   25172   2015-11-03        1
   31699   2015-12-11        1
   32186   2015-12-14        2
   43426   2016-01-13        1
   68300   2016-04-04        2
   71926   2016-04-19        1
```

I would like to rank the events by chronological order (1 to n), for each user.

I can achieve this by doing :

```
df.groupby('user_id')['occurred_at'].rank(method='dense')
```

However, for those 2 lines, that occurred on the same date (for the same user), I end up with the same rank :

```
   20996   2015-10-15        1
   20998   2015-10-15        1
```

In case the event date is the same, I would like to compare the `event_id` and arbitrarily rank lower the event with the lowest `event_id`. How can I achieve this easily ?

I can post process the ranks to make sure every rank is only used once, but this seems pretty bulky...

**Edit** : how to reproduce :

Copy paste the data in `data.csv` file.
Then :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', delim_whitespace=True)
df['rank'] = df.groupby('user_id')['occurred_at'].rank(method='dense')
>>> df[df['user_id'] == 1]
    event_id occurred_at  user_id  rank
0      19148  2015-10-01        1   1.0
2      20589  2015-10-12        1   2.0
3      20996  2015-10-15        1   3.0 <--
4      20998  2015-10-15        1   3.0 <--
6      23630  2015-10-26        1   4.0
7      25172  2015-11-03        1   5.0
8      31699  2015-12-11        1   6.0
10     43426  2016-01-13        1   7.0
12     71926  2016-04-19        1   8.0
```

Am using python3 and pandas 0.18.1

Comment: I can't reproduce this: `0     1.0
1     1.0
2     2.0
3     3.0
4     3.0
5     2.0
6     4.0
7     5.0
8     6.0
9     3.0
10    7.0
11    4.0
12    8.0` it works for me

Comment: Hmm, I think this is a bug, it should not do this, I can reproduce this now I understand your issue, can you post an issue on https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues

Comment: This looks like a bug, the `rank` method is not handling strings correctly, if you convert the date column to `datetime` `dtype` then it works as expected if you see the answer below. Additionally if you pass `method='first' there is an `AttributeError` I'd post this as an issue as it should work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort_values('event_id')` prior to grouping then pass `method='first'` to `rank`

Also note that if `occurred_at` isn't already `datetime`, make it `datetime`.

```
# unnecessary if already datetime, but doesn't hurt to do it anyway
df.occurred_at = pd.to_datetime(df.occurred_at) 

df['rank'] = df.sort_values('event_id') \
                 .groupby('user_id').occurred_at \
                 .rank(method='first')
df
```

[image]

---

#### Reference for complete verifiable code

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """event_id  occurred_at  user_id
   19148   2015-10-01        1
   19693   2015-10-05        2
   20589   2015-10-12        1
   20996   2015-10-15        1
   20998   2015-10-15        1
   23301   2015-10-23        2
   23630   2015-10-26        1
   25172   2015-11-03        1
   31699   2015-12-11        1
   32186   2015-12-14        2
   43426   2016-01-13        1
   68300   2016-04-04        2
   71926   2016-04-19        1"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True)

df.occurred_at = pd.to_datetime(df.occurred_at) 

df['rank'] = df.sort_values('event_id').groupby('user_id').occurred_at.rank(method='first')

df
```

Comment: What version pandas is this? it fails with `ValueError` on `0.18.1`

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute '_aggregate_item_by_item'` for some reason, my numpy version is `1.11.0` python 64-bit 3.4.3.5

Comment: @EdChum I'll check numpy in a second.  I added complete code snippet for you to test.

Comment: @EdChum `np.__version__` is `1.11.0` as well

Comment: Yes the issue is that if the date column is still a string then it fails, converting to `datetime` works so I think this is a bug

Comment: I assumed OP had datetime.  Good idea to explicitly call that out.  I'll edit to include that.

Comment: Thx EdChum and jezrael

Comment: @jezrael If you switch those two rows in question, `20996` and `20998`, you'll get different results depending on whether you sort ahead of time.  This is a more general solution.

Comment: Changing `occurred_at` to `datetime`, and using `sort_values` indeed did the job. Thanks for pointing it out.